# Accessing data returned by ajax request on load

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've been working on a single page site in which data from a single json file is rendered variously in different sections - nothing displayed on load, but only upon click event. I learned a little about callbacks getting that wired up, but as I almost completed it I realized how flawed the concept was, so now I'm back to the drawing board.

My idea now is to make the ajax call onload, set the json result as a variable available to several functions. I thought it would go something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var myJsonData = function() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "/json/someJsonData.json", true);
        request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    var myJsonArray = myJsonString["Projects"];
                    return myJsonArray;
                }
            }
        } // onreadystatechange
    } // var myJsonData

    myJsonData(); // *
    console.log("myJsonArray: " + myJsonArray); // undefined
```

Or:

```
window.onload = function() {
    myJsonData();
}

function myJsonData() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "/json/someJsonData.json", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var myJsonArray = myJsonString["Projects"];
                alert("you are here (myJsonArray defined)");
                alert("myJsonArray: " + myJsonArray);
                console.log("myJsonArray: " + myJsonArray);
                return myJsonArray;
            }
        }
    } // onreadystatechange
} // var myJsonData

console.log("myJsonArray: " + myJsonArray); // undefined
```

Or:

```
window.onload = myJsonData;
// etc.
```

Of course myJsonArray is undefined either way. I'm obviously missing something fundamental about how to do this (or is this even a bad idea altogether?). Is there some way to pass a result as a callback when invoking an ajax request on load?

Can someone please enlighten me as to how to proceed from here, a skeletal example perhaps ? (p.s. still focusing on native js, not jQuery)

Many thanks in advance,

svs

Comment: async/sync request... read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), set last parameter to `false`.

Comment: @skobaljic Thanks. I'm a little surprised to see a sugg to go sync, seems to contradict everything I've read about sync/async. Even the page you referred to says, "Using async=false is not recommended". Would a structural change be better advised/more conventional?

Comment: You can use async, but than only after you get json response you can call your app `init` function, define app variables etc. Since this data is important, you can start loading at very beginning on the page, expecting data will be available by main page load. While loading, you can place a loading spinner. But what you cannot do is: return `myJsonArray` for `function myJsonData()` inside the xhr async call.

Comment: @skobaljic Thx again. Understood, and I think I now have a solution, I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things wrong in the code. First the myJsonArray is local to the function myJsonData(). You have to define it globally. Second, the ajax request is async. You have to wait for the result before working with it. Here is a working example based on your code:

```
   var myJsonArray;  //Globally defined
        window.onload = function() {

            var outputData = function() {
                console.log(myJsonArray);
            }

            var myJsonData = function() {
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "someJsonData.json", true);
                request.send(null);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState === 4) {
                        if (request.status === 200) {

                            myJsonArray = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                            outputData(); //Ouput when result is received
                        }
                    }

                } // onreadystatechange


            } // var myJsonData

            myJsonData(); // *

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I thought I should be avoiding use of a global variable but in any case it seems that whether I use window.onload or (function() {...})(), some version of a callback in the ajax is required. I think what I was missing earlier was that it boils down to a scope issue; that whatever function I have actually rendering the data on the page has to be either a child or a sibling of the ajax function. Cheers! svs

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript promises could solve your problem here. [Promises are native to ES6](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/), although obviously the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility) isn't quite fully there yet. Regardless, here is how you could implement your code with promises:

```
window.onload = function () {
  myJsonData().then(function (result) {
      console.log("myJsonArray: " + result);
      alert(result.one);
      // do something else here
  });
}

function myJsonData() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two", true);
      request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      request.send(null);
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState === 4) {
              if (request.status === 200) {
                  var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                  //var myJsonArray = myJsonString["Projects"];
                  resolve(myJsonString);
              }
          }
      } // onreadystatechange
  });
} // var myJsonData
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unhujd7d/)

Comment: Thank you. This is not the first I've heard about Promises in context of async/callback questions. I think I need to work with callbacks (and js101 in general) before I move on to the brave new world of ES6. But I'll get there! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and understanding.

When you are dealing with sync function and async function, always it is important to know which functions require data from the async callback function.

If the functions fully depend on the data received, it will a good coding practice to call these function in the loop

```
if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {
        var myJsonString = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // call the function which depend on the data received here.
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend setting the async as false as it would just result in page freeze sometimes.